# Selecting a specific part of a string C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to create a new string, which removes certain characters from an existing string e.g.

```
string path = "C:\test.txt"
```

so string "pathminus" will take out the "C:\" e.g.

```
string pathminus = "test.txt"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string class offers all sorts of ways to do this.

If you want to change "C:\test.txt" to "test.txt" by removing the first three characters:

```
path.Substring(3);
```

If you want to remove "C:\" from anywhere in the string:

```
path.Replace("C:\", "");
```

Or if you specifically want the filename, regardless of how long the path is:

```
Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Depending on your intentions, there are many ways to do it. I prefer using the static class `Path`.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

Eg:

```
string pathminus = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Answer (score 11):

There's so many ways that you can remove the a certain part of a string. These are a couple of ways to do it:

```
var path = @"C:\test.txt";
var root = @"C:\";
```

**Using `string.Remove()`**

```
var pathWithoutRoot = path.Remove(0, root.Length);
Console.WriteLine(pathWithoutRoot);                // prints test.txt
```

**Using `string.Replace()`**

```
pathWithoutRoot = path.Replace(root, "");
Console.WriteLine(pathWithoutRoot);                // prints test.txt
```

**Using `string.Substring()`**

```
pathWithoutRoot = path.Substring(root.Length);
Console.WriteLine(pathWithoutRoot);                // prints test.txt
```

**Using `Path.GetFileName()`**

```
pathWithoutRoot = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine(pathWithoutRoot);                // prints test.txt
```

You can also use Regular Expression to find and replace parts of a string, this is a little bit harder though. [You can read on MSDN on how to use Regular Expressions in C#.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Here's a complete sample on how to use `string.Remove()`, `string.Replace()`, `string.Substring()`, `Path.GetFileName()` and `Regex.Replace()`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = @"C:\test.txt";
            var root = @"C:\";

            var pathWithoutRoot = path.Remove(0, root.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(pathWithoutRoot);

            pathWithoutRoot = Path.GetFileName(path);
            Console.WriteLine(pathWithoutRoot);

            pathWithoutRoot = path.Replace(root, "");
            Console.WriteLine(pathWithoutRoot);

            pathWithoutRoot = path.Substring(root.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(pathWithoutRoot);

            var pattern = "C:\\\\";
            var regex = new Regex(pattern);

            pathWithoutRoot = regex.Replace(path, "");
            Console.WriteLine(pathWithoutRoot);
        }
    }
}
```

It all depends on what you want to do with the string, in this case you might want to remove just `C:\` but next time you might want to do other types of operations with the string, maybe remove the tail or such, then the above different methods might help you out.

Answer (score 2):

For this specific example, I would look into the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) Class. For your example, you can just call:

```
string pathminus = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) method?

Answer (score 0):

If the string is actually a file path, use the `Path.GetFileName` method to get the file name part of it.

Answer (score 0):

`path.SubString(path.IndexOf('\'))`

Answer (score 0):

You want `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` but exactly what are you trying do here?

In its simplest form:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void RemoveDriveFromPath()
    {
        string path = @"C:\test.txt";

        Assert.AreEqual("test.txt", System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(path, @"^[A-Z]\:\\", string.Empty));
    }
```

Are you just trying to get the file name of a file without the path?

If so do this instead:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetJustFileName()
    {
        string path = @"C:\test.txt";

        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

        Assert.AreEqual("test.txt", fileInfo.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For more general strings, use the `string.Split(inputChar)`, which takes a character as a parameter and splits the string into a `string[]` wherever that inputChar is found.

```
string[] stringArr = path.Split('\\'); // need double \ because \ is an escape character
// you can now concatenate any part of the string array to get what you want. 
// in this case, it's just the last piece
string pathminus = stringArr[stringArr.Length-1];
```